# C++ static constexpr using input value

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

My code has to get something from the user as simulation value, and then perform the simulation. However, I have a large number of objects of a class that are in a vector of another class, and of course i have to operate on them. I wanted thus to make two variables that once calculated are constant, and make them constexpr, such that they would be accessible by any instance, so i choose static constexpr, but upon reviewing my ansewrs, i noticed that the value, of this expression is simulation depend, and i thought it could be nice, if i actually could make the choise through an interface and not on compilation. However, now i can not define my static constexpr. Thus I added on my namespace of const values, another one, which would be determined by the user and then used by the program to define my static constexpr. However upon compilation i get the error, as indicated below. Do you have any proposals, any suggestions why i have that problem??

```
namespace physique{
    
    constexpr double R=8.3144621;
    constexpr double Mmolaire=0.03896;
    constexpr double g=9.81;
    constexpr double Mmolairedeau=0.0180153;
    constexpr double Tinf(double Tinf_simulator){return Tinf_simulator;}
    
}

class cubedair{
    private: static constexpr double enthalpie=(7.0/2)*(physique::R/physique::Mmolaire)*(physique::Tinf);
             static constexpr double bernoulic=(1.0/2)*pow(6,2)+enthalpie;
             double enthalpieppm;
             double temperature;
}

class cubedair{
    private: static constexpr double enthalpie=(7/2)*(physique::R/physique::Mmolaire)*(physique::Tinf);
             static constexpr double bernoulic=(1/2)*pow(6,2)+enthalpie;
             double enthalpieppm;
             double temperature;
```

Comment: Please don't just post a wall of text. Format it into sections and paragraphs, to make it readable.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add the error message. Also, I don't think `7/2` is going to do what you want.

Comment: And please be aware of *integer divisions*, which will give integer results.

Comment: `Tinf` is a function, not a plain value. `someValue*Tinf` dosn't make sense; `Tinf` needs to be called with a parameter, as in `someValue*Tinf(someParam)`. Taking a step back, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve by adding a function that simply returns its argument unchanged. There is no magic that would let you create a compile-time constant whose value somehow depends on the run-time user input.